# Access to mysql directory in Google Cloud SQL

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I had a MySQL database in Google Cloud Platform, one of the tables failed and I need to access the Ubuntu instance to recover the innodb files from the database. But it only gives me access to the MySQL client.

Comment: Do you have access to the Google Cloud SQL instance? When you talk about the _mysql client_, are you talking about the Cloud Shell? What tool do you want to use for fixing your database, MySQL Workbench? PHPMyAdmin? Adminer? Please edit your question and provide us a little more context if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Google Cloud SQL provides a [fully-managed service](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/) endpoint. This means that you cannot access directly to the virtual machine; Instead, you have access only to the MySQL database client.

An available option to perform a point-in-time recovery is the [Restoring an instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/restoring) alternative where you can use a [backup file](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/backup-recovery/backups) to restore the instance to the same instance or to a different one.